# In the prayer "Al Ken Nekaveh Lecha", are we hoping that all humanity will convert to Judaism?

Tags: tefilla, aleinu-leshabeiach

The paragraph following the payer "Aleinu", that begins with the words "Al Ken Nekaveh Lecha" [See p. 331 here](http://www.2bjewish.com/RoshHashSample.pdf) contains phrasing that indicates our hope that all humanity will recognize G-d's name and will bend their knee and praise only you (G-d), and each tongue swear only to you..."

Does this paragraph imply that Jews are hoping that in the future all humanity will be Jewish? There's is nothing in the paragraph that specifically mentions conversion.

Comment: No only that they keep the 7 noehid laws

Comment: `There's is nothing in the paragraph that specifically mentions conversion` So why would you think it is talking about conversion? || Given that the premise to your question is that there is no evidence that it refers to conversion, how would one go about answering this? Expressing personal opinion? Citing a source about Alenu? Citing some general source about the messianic age? Something else? Consider clarifying what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Recognizing/praising God and being a non-Jew are not mutually exclusive, so there is no indication in this prayer that everyone will be Jewish.

Answer (score 0):

not hoping, it is inevitable that the truth will come out as Rashi comments on the Shema (Devarim 6:4)

> *The Lord is our God; the Lord is one:* The Lord, who is now our God and
>   not the God of the other nations-He will be [declared] in the future
>   “the one God,” as it is said: “For then I will convert the peoples to
>   a pure language that all of them call in the name of the Lord” (Zeph.
>   3:9), and it is [also] said: “On that day will the Lord be one and His
>   name one” (Zech. 14:9). (see Sifrei)

we are just expressing our longing for this future time. not that everyone will be Jewish just that the truth will come out and falsehood will be banished

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question specifically about the phrasing in the prayer.

Comment: @DanF how about now?

Comment: Actually, I think Rashi holds that in the future everyone will be Jewish (the Rambam does not), but either way, yes, that is the intent of the prayer.

Comment: @Yishai so how do you explain no Gerim in the days of moshiach

Comment: @ray, that is a question on Rashi, not me. Does Rashi even hold that? I have no idea.

Comment: @Yishai where do you see from the wording of the prayer that everyone will be Jewish? and how do you define jewish? do u consider a noahide jewish?

Comment: @ray, I think it is just ambiguous in the prayer. It could work according to both opinions. You just asserted that "not that everyone will be Jewish" while quoting Rashi, so I was pointing out that Rashi's intent likely isn't that. (It can be hard to know with Rashi as he will follow different opinions in different places without letting you know).

Comment: @Yishai i dont see any indication that everyone will be jewish. the verse rashi brings just says everyone will accept God's sovereignty. this is due to His revealing Himself to humanity not to any kind of conversion

Comment: No, Rashi says it in a different place.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion, the statement about bending the knee and recognizing HaShem does not imply that everyone will be necessarily Jewish. 
It DOES imply that ALL nations of the world will finally recognize that there is but ONE GOD and that he is (for all of us) OUR GOD.

Again in my opinion people try to look for hidden meanings in prayers, instead of accepting the words for what they are, much too often.